# I need to convert some dictionary keys from string to integer, but I am getting an "invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Manolo/PycharmProjects/nolosprog/SchoolProg/lab14.py", line
>   23, in 
>       prices_and_dates.update({i: int(price_of_gas)}) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.068'

Comment: try `int(float(1.068))` (which will give you `1`)

Comment: So, where is your code?

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you add some code with failing example?

Comment: You should use a `float` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python does not know how to convert '1.068' to int. It knows how to convert it to float.
Than you can decide to covert the float to an int.

so use
`int(float(price_of_gas))`

Comment: But this will severely round the price, which probably isn't what the OP expects. Maybe he should simply convert to float.

Comment: he asked for int. If he wants float float(price_of_gas) will work.